# Ruby how to reloop program and make a class

Tags: ruby

I'm making a simple quiz program in ruby but I need help with answering the quiz question
I'm quite bad at this whole ruby thing but I'll try to explain, I want the program to Loop when the answer isn't A,B,C or D but I also want the program to be able to not care if the answer is A or a or B or b and what every else, I've gotten the syntax errors of the constant A being undefined and unexpected Ends and stuff.

```
require 'colorize'
require 'win32console'

puts "Hello! And Welcome the game that you shall name!".yellow  
puts "My name is Wuz and I shall be your guide for the time being!".yellow
print "Now young quester, what shall I call you?".yellow
call_you = gets.chomp
puts "Okay quester #{call_you} now we shall name the game!".yellow
print "Okay #{call_you} what shall the game be named?".yellow
named = gets.chomp
puts "#{call_you}! this game shall be called #{named}!".yellow
puts "I Will give you some instructions to begin the game and then I will be off as I have business to attend to in other parts of the internet!".yellow
puts "This is a simple text quiz game which will test your wits and other things!"
puts "To answer the questions in green all you must do is either input A,B,C or D or enter the correct word/number"
print "Ok?"
puts "Lets do a trial question!"

puts "What color is an orange?"

puts "A)Black"
puts "B)Red"
puts "C)Orange"
puts "D)Every colour!"
print "What shall you say?".red

say = gets
if
  say = A
  put "Wrong!".red
elsif
  say = B
  put "Wrong!".red
elsif
  say = C
  put "Right! Good job!".green
elsif
  say = D
  put "Wrong!".red
end
```

Comment: You should put the conditions for `if` statements on the same line as the `if` itself. Also you probably mean to use `==` in the comparisons. And probably also `"A"` (the string), etc., instead of `A` (the constant).

Comment: Good luck with your homework.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a lot of text to include, you might consider putting larger blocks of it
in text files or [Here documents](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Here_documents).  This is an example of the latter:

```
GREETING =<<_
puts "Hello! And Welcome the game that you shall name!".yellow  
puts "My name is Wuz and I shall be your guide for the time being!".yellow
_

INSTRUCTIONS =<<THE_END
I Will give you some instructions to begin the game and then I will be off as
I have business to attend to in other parts of the internet!
This is a simple text quiz game which will test your wits and other things!
To answer the questions in green all you must do is either input A,B,C or D
or enter the correct word/number.

Ok?
Let's do a trial question!

What color is an orange?

A) Black
B) Red
C) Orange
D) Every colour!
THE_END
```

We can now use these constants in your code:

```
puts GREETING

print "Now young quester, what shall I call you?"
call_you = gets.chomp

puts "Okay quester #{call_you} now we shall name the game!".
print "Okay #{call_you} what shall the game be named?"
named = gets.chomp

puts "#{call_you}! this game shall be called #{named}!"

puts INSTRUCTIONS
```

You may wish to ask your question within a loop and then break out when a valid answer is given.  After getting the answer to the question in the variable, I've use a `case` statement to process the response.  First, I convert the response to uppercase, in case a lowercase letter was entered.

If the answer is `"C"` (or `"c"`), `"Right! Good job!"` is printed and the loop is exited. 
If the answer is "A", "B", "D", `"Wrong!"` is printed and the loop is existed. If any other answer is given, the loop is repeated.

```
say = nil
loop do
  print "What shall you say? "
  say = gets.strip
  case say.upcase
  when "C"
    puts "Right! Good job!"
    break
  when "A", "B", "D"
    puts "Wrong!"
    break
  else
    puts "Invalid entry"
  end
end
puts "#{say} was entered"
```

The only reason for the first line, `say = nil` is to initialize the variable `say`, so that its value can be retrieved after the end of the block.  `say` can be initialized to any value.  If this statement is omitted, the scope of `say` is restricted to the block.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of issues here.

```
if
say = A
```

assigns the value of variable A to say and tests if that is true, rather than compare the value of "A" to say.
To do what I think you are trying to do should be something like

```
if say.chomp == "A"
  puts ....
```

Also please clean up the structure ... `puts"blah"` should be puts "blah", etc.

**Update:**
to address the question in the comment

maybe you can put the whole thing in a while loop:

```
wrong_answer = true

while wrong_answer do 
...
...
# for the correct response case
if say.chomp == "A" 
puts ....
wrong_answer = false
```

Comment: What do you mean by clean the structure, as in add a space when ever I do a puts, so like puts "Hello" instead of puts"Hello"?

Comment: By the way that worked perfect thanks! But how would I start the program at the question again if the user gets it wrong?

Comment: @user3528125 yes that's what i was referring to , the spaces , etc. I should have said clean up the formatting.